# Is there something that can be done about these WARN messages or should I not worry about them?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, syslog, intel

I was using zoom and these messages popped up on my laptop's /var/log/syslog. I am using Ubuntu 19.10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220i. My kernel version is: 5.3.0-42-generic

```
Mar 16 14:45:07 a thermald[617]: [WARN]sysfs write failed /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/enabled
Mar 16 14:45:07 a kernel: [18300.593089] powercap intel-rapl:0: package locked by BIOS, monitoring only
Mar 16 14:45:07 a thermald[617]: [WARN]sysfs write failed /sys/devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl/intel-rapl:0/constraint_0_power_limit_uw
Mar 16 14:45:12 a kernel: [18305.601751] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:45:12 a thermald[617]: [WARN]sysfs write failed /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate//no_turbo
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.311822] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.311826] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.311832] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.311835] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.312809] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.312811] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.312813] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:45:21 a kernel: [18314.312814] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:45:22 a kernel: [18315.618828] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
Mar 16 14:45:26 a kernel: [18319.812404] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 01
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.932256] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 40
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.936096] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.940073] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.940286] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.941296] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.942272] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.944073] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.946531] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:27 a kernel: [18320.948072] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 02
Mar 16 14:45:44 a kernel: [18337.857079] intel_powerclamp: Stop forced idle injection
Mar 16 14:45:44 a kernel: [18337.857608] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:45:52 a kernel: [18345.868126] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:46:02 a kernel: [18355.884437] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
Mar 16 14:46:52 a kernel: [18406.269403] intel_powerclamp: Stop forced idle injection
Mar 16 14:46:52 a kernel: [18406.270253] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:46:55 a kernel: [18408.668109] perf: interrupt took too long (8008 > 7948), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 24750
Mar 16 14:47:05 a kernel: [18418.285694] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:47:14 a kernel: [18427.302913] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
Mar 16 14:50:08 a kernel: [18602.262278] perf: interrupt took too long (10329 > 10010), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 19250
Mar 16 14:47:05 a thermald[617]: message repeated 4 times: [ [WARN]sysfs write failed /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate//no_turbo]
Mar 16 14:51:27 a dbus-daemon[611]: [system] Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' requested by ':1.66' (uid=1000 pid=1089 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdev" label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Mar 16 14:51:28 a org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper: QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object
Mar 16 14:51:28 a kernel: [18681.550443] intel_powerclamp: Stop forced idle injection
Mar 16 14:51:28 a org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper: message repeated 2 times: [ QDBusArgument: read from a write-only object]
Mar 16 14:51:28 a dbus-daemon[611]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
Mar 16 14:51:28 a thermald[617]: [WARN]sysfs write failed /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate//no_turbo
Mar 16 14:51:28 a kernel: [18681.558076] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:51:39 a kernel: [18692.630741] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.457756] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5677)
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.457759] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5677)
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.457762] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5677)
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.457765] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5677)
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.458797] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.458801] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.458804] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:51:45 a kernel: [18698.458808] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 16 14:51:49 a kernel: [18702.688444] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
Mar 16 14:52:34 a kernel: [18748.030287] intel_powerclamp: Stop forced idle injection
Mar 16 14:52:34 a kernel: [18748.031053] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:52:34 a kernel: [18748.185669] perf: interrupt took too long (13118 > 12911), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 15000
Mar 16 14:52:56 a kernel: [18770.058709] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:53:06 a kernel: [18780.073443] intel_powerclamp: Start idle injection to reduce power
Mar 16 14:53:18 a kernel: [18792.092764] intel_powerclamp: Stop forced idle injection
Mar 16 14:53:18 a kernel: [18792.093307] intel_pstate: Turbo disabled by BIOS or unavailable on processor
Mar 16 14:53:18 a thermald[617]: message repeated 4 times: [ [WARN]sysfs write failed /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate//no_turbo]
```

Comment: It looks like your CPU was overheating. Is your laptop not getting good air flow? Is there anything that you can see that would be causing this?

Comment: Well the sun had started to glare on it and it felt a bit hot, however it always sits on my lap and has not happened before. I was using zoom at the time with 5 people and the sound started deteriorating after 40 minutes in the meeting, maybe due to this overheating. I also had two browser windows open with 5 tabs each. I am a bit concerned that if i am having the meetings again, this might happen again. I have the latest Ubuntu updates on it.

Comment: Others have had this same issue and they are pointing at ``thermald``. They claim that ``thermald`` on their systems was causing the CPU to throttle when it shouldn't be. As a workaround you can disable it with ```systemctl stop thermald```. Feel free to see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1600599 for more information

Answer (score 0):

My friend's computer started doing this, he doesn't use it as a laptop, it's immobile hooked to a TV.  It's visibly dusty, and it's kinject'ing to keep CPU temp in 90-95C range.  He's blown out the dust before and then it stays cools enough to not kinject so I'm sure in his case that is the solution.

I know I'm necro'ing an old thread, but most likely if this is happening you've got dust in the cooling system.  Or, the system is undercooled by design (some vendors seem to just love having fanless setups with CPUs that really need a fan, or keep fan at low speed when it's hot enough it should give up and ramp up a bit.)

Comment: I also disassembled it, cleaned out the fan and replaced the thermal paste. Hasn't had this problem since.